# Adding rows and columns in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to add rows and columns in FabricJs Canvas.

Here is code on normal canvas:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    columns = 6,
    rows = 4,
    w, h, tileWidth, tileHeight;
```

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/q5j3Q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle, it contains FabricJS code to implement a grid.
Remember that FabricJS is a wrapper around the HTML 5 Canvas API.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9sLu/1205/)

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 50;

// create grid
for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}
```